# Executing program with an DAT file and input

Tags: c++

How am I able to execute my C++ program together with a .DAT file and an input?

For example:
`./program.exe file.dat 5`

Example of multiple command lines in file.dat:

```
addpeer 12130
removepeer 13820
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, your use the main function `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, argc contains the "argument count" i.e. the number of your arguments, and argv is a vector containing the arguments you provided when you called your program. In your case it will contain "file.dat" and 5. Once you have this you can parse your file with your program and do what you want with it.

Comment: Hi Etienne, thanks! You mean the program will run a N times depending on the number of command lines in file.DAT? To use the value '5', i simply have to use argc?

Comment: I meant in your C++ program you can read the argv vector and work with the arguments you provided when you started the program. Then you can work with those arguments as variables in your C++ program.